# android: resetting rollover count

Tags: android, logcat

i just encountered an odd behavior while developing and debugging an android app on my nexus 7. log cat prompts me with always the same error message, pretty much every 60 seconds.

```
E    07-08 15:38:08.575   566   qcom_sensors_hal   hal_process_time_resp: Resetting rollover count from 0 to 7
E    07-08 15:39:07.673   566   qcom_sensors_hal   hal_process_time_resp: Resetting rollover count from 0 to 7
E    07-08 15:40:14.388   566   qcom_sensors_hal   hal_process_time_resp: Resetting rollover count from 0 to 7
```

i'm pretty sure, it has nothing to do with my app, since it constantly shows up, regardless of whether my app is running or not.

nevertheless i would be interested, what causes this message and if it's something i should worry about.

Answer (score 1):

There is a whole redit post devoted to this, it might be worth checking out this: http://www.reddit.com/r/Nexus5/comments/20g0vj/150_linessec_qcom_sensors_hal_logcat_spam_causing/

Answer (score 1):

There is also this discussion on a Google Code Library with GL Memory errors and this comes up - https://code.google.com/p/libgdx/issues/detail?id=1427.

Seems to be an error caused by an OEM library for whatever sensor it is trying to use at that time.  It is having trouble getting a response that it likes, so it sets a timeout and tries again, and again and again until it gets satisfied.  Could be any sensor, but looks like most common culprit is the accelerometer or something in Location Services.